# Custom Column Size in Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

hey guys am working on this website where i have left column and a wide right column. Now the left column is somewhere between large-3.5 and the right column falls about 8.5.
**My Question is can I customise the column using an id like say it's width and that if I do that will it still be responsive and behave like a normal foundation grid
thanks.**

**Ps:I tried giving the left columns a class and set its width to 383 px.
But the layout  just totally crashed.
Please help.
thanks.**

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: @simbabque i am in middle of my project so i am scared of doing it now. jsut asking for assurance.

Comment: If you have version control, branch. If not, make a copy of the code, and play around there.

Comment: @simbabque ok let me check.

Comment: @simbabque read my update

Comment: Please show some actual code, or build a jsfiddle.

Comment: here i have uploaded a demo. you can see that on right ive added 2 pics  and on left the columns should fix in such a way that on right the pics align to right. now columns don't have any margins or paddings http://beautifulsoftwares.com/grid/

Answer (score 2):

You can make custom columns by finding where the other columns are called in the `/css/foundation.css` file and adding your own classes next to the other column calls at the various browser sizes. Here's an example for a 3.5 column (remember you can't use `large-3.5` as a class name)

Example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 71.250em) { 
    .large-3andAHalf { width: 35%; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 50em) {
    .medium-3andAHalf { width: 35%; }
}
@media only screen { {
    .small-3andAHalf { width: 35%; }
}
```

Be sure to change the media query and figure out the percentages based on how many columns your grid is using and what your min-width monitor sizes are set to, this is what it would be for a 10 column grid on a 1100px design.

The thing to keep in mind if you use this method is that you'll need to create another custom set of columns in order to make your container fill 100% and not leave 1/2 columns floating around (3.5 columns + 6 columns ≠ 10 columns) which will leave large spaces in your deisgn that are usually undesirable by the designers.